# sdl screen UTF8 screen window caption

Tags: c++, utf-8, screen, sdl, caption

I was trying to set UTF8 screen window caption in my sdl project by all I see is `????` and I have no idea how to deal with it. Here is my sample code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    int screen_width = 800;
    int screen_hight = 600;
    int screen_bpp = 32;
    SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
        SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( screen_width, screen_hight, screen_bpp, SDL_SWSURFACE  );

        // Set the window caption
        SDL_WM_SetCaption( "تستی", NULL ); //utf8 not working
        SDL_Delay(5000);
        SDL_Flip(screen);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inputting it like this won't work, unless by some compiler extension. You could convert it to UTF-8 code units (for example [here](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)):

> D8 AA D8 B3 D8 AA DB 8C

And then put that into a char literal using hex escapes (`\xHH` where `HH` is hex value):

```
SDL_WM_SetCaption( "\xD8\xAA\xD8\xB3\xD8\xAA\xDB\x8C", NULL );
```

This should work provided your system can display that.

Obviously this is tedious to do so if you have a lot of UTF-8 strings, you could put them into a UTF-8 encoded file and read from there, or see if your compiler supports UTF-8 literals (they look like this: `u8"تستی"`).